# Is it possible to construct eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Hamiltonian based on its subspaces?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am having hard times with finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix. The only property that I have found, it is expressible as sum of one even and one odd matrix.

```
H(k) = H_1(k) + H_2 (k)
```

Where I considered first one as even and second one as odd. Can I construct eigenvalues and eigenvectors of H(k) in terms of two other matrices?  As far as I know, if a vector space is direct sum of its subspaces, then it is possible to add the bases of different subspaces to construct a full basis for whole space. Since writing in terms of even and odd is sort of writing in terms of direct subspaces, I am wondering the possibility of what I want.

Comment: What are 'even' and 'odd' matrices?

Comment: I doubt this leads to anything: the eigenvectors of $A+B$ cannot be determined from the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$ in general

Comment: @daw What I meant is, $H_1(-k) = H_1(k)$ and $H_2(-k) = -H_2(k)$.

Comment: It seems that this is valid for polynomials but not for matrices.